# Put request/function does not update my API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, put

my user has a select option to change the owner property of my contact object. I've written a put request which my component inherits through props, along with the other owner options.

however, when I submit the changes, the change isn't actually saved. I think the problem may be the event from the submit button (which when I console log it out, is 'null').
If I console out the 'contact' from the 'handleSellSubmit' function it seems okay I'm not sure what I've done wrong here

```
const SellContact = (props) =>{


const options = props.owners.map((owner, index) =>{
  return <option key={owner.id} value={owner._links.self.href}>{owner.name}</option>
})



function handleSellSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  const contact = {
    "id": props.contact_id,
    "owner": event.target.owner.value,
  }
this.handleSellclick(contact);
}


return(
  <div>
  <form onSubmit={handleSellSubmit}>
  <select name="owner" id="owner">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Buyer</option>
    {options}
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}
```

the handleSellClick function which is inherited from props is

```
  handleSellclick(contact){
    let request = new Request();
    request.put(`/api/contacts/${this.props.id}`, contact).then(() =>{
        window.location= '/'
    });
  }
```

For reference...the 'contact' when consoled-logged out is

```
{id: "4", owner: "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/4"}
id: "4"
owner: "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/4"
```

Comment: what does the route look like on your api? Also, the route is owners/4 what is the expected object on the back end? What happens if you try and send the request via postman or curl?

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi I've tried on insomnia to put and it's been fine.   owners/4 is  an owner object.  `{
  "name" : "Owner4",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/4"
    },
    "owner" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/owners/4{?projection}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}` .   and if I go to `http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/` with the index of a contact, I see the expected contact.

Comment: Contacts is like so....  `{
  "_embedded" : {
    "contacts" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "owner" : {
        "name" : "Owner1"
      },
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/1"
        },
        "contact" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/1{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "owner" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/1/owner{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        }
      }
    },
`

Comment: Are you getting a 200 when you put from client side?

Comment: @LeonardoTrimarchi yes, getting 200